# Second word always disappears when using typeText in Xcode UITest

Tags: uitextview, xcode-ui-testing

I have a UITest, and I'm trying to confirm the text is being saved correctly, entering it like so:

```
let wonderfulTextView = elementsQuery.textViews["Wonderful"]
wonderfulTextView.tap()
wonderfulTextView.typeText("Think of all the beauty left around you and be happy")
```

But it's always missing the second word, regardless of what text I put in. The above would end up "Think all the beauty..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by making sure that the hardware keyboard was disconnected in the simulator.

[image: how to disconnect hardware keyboard]

Comment: Great that you found this! I was completely lost by this erratic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

My app `let shopEasyApp = XCUIApplication()` has a UI test that requires to enter text in a `TextField`. `textField` is a property of my viewModel called `dataSource`.
If I enter the text with

```
shopEasyApp.textFields[kNewItemTextFieldID].typeText("A new item\n")
```

the `textField` is submitted, and in `.onSubmit` I see in the debugger

```
(lldb) po dataSource.textFieldText
"a nw item"
```

i.e. the 4th character is missing.

If I do it with

```
func slowlyTypeText(text: String) {
    let textField = shopEasyApp.textFields[kNewItemTextFieldID]
    for nextCharacter in text {
        textField.typeText(String(nextCharacter))
    }
}
//...
slowlyTypeText(text: "A new item\n")
```

the text is typed slowly, and in `.onSubmit` I see in the debugger

```
(lldb) po dataSource.textFieldText
"a new item"
```

This indicates to me that this is still a bug in Xcode UI tests.

As @Hannele in her answer explained, this error is avoided, if the Simulator hardware keyboard is disabled.